# Not able to reduce related JavaScript objects in an array

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I am trying to group related JavaScript objects in an array by key.

But, I'm at stuck at a point.

I have a JavaScript object array something like this:

```
[
    {
        "text": "hello world",
        "startPos": 0,
        "endPos": 12,
        "value": "hello world",
        "entity": "Greeting"
    },
    {
        "text": "hello world",
        "startPos": 0,
        "endPos": 6,
        "value": "hello",
        "entity": "Greeting"
    }
]
```

I made the following code, but I was stuck.

```js
a = [
  {
    "text": "hello world",
    "startPos": 0,
    "endPos": 12,
    "value": "hello world",
    "entity": "Greeting"
  },
  {
    "text": "hello world",
    "startPos": 0,
    "endPos": 6,
    "value": "hello",
    "entity": "Greeting"
  }
]

let result = a.reduce((acc, d) => {
  const found = acc.find(a => a.text == d.text);
  const entitiesArray = {
    startPos: d.startPos,
    endPos: d.endPos,
    entity: d.entity
  };
  if (found) {
    found.entities.push(entitiesArray);
  } else {
    acc.push({});
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 4));
```

The JavaScript object are being repeated based on the `"text"` key. I want to group the above array into one object based on the `"text"` key.

Something like this:

```
[
    {
        "text": "hello world",
        "entities": [
                {
                    "startPos": 0,
                    "endPos": 12,
                    "value": "hello world",
                    "entity": "Greeting"
                },
                {
                    "startPos": 0,
                    "endPos": 6,
                    "value": "hello",
                    "entity": "Greeting"
                }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Do you expect `"text": "hello world"` in second object? Or is it copy paste issue

Comment: Why is the first entity has no `text` and the second entity has no `entity`?

Comment: No, I am getting two "distinct" objects whose `text` key is same, I want to group them.

Comment: But the objects you have on your entities (desired output) are different from what you started

Comment: @Eddie updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to add the object with `text` into the array when `found` is false. So in the next iterations it can't be able to find object comparing their texts

Also if your IDE and Engines support new ES proposal, you can use [**Rest/Spread Properties**](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread)

```js
const a = [
  {
    "text": "hello world",
    "startPos": 0,
    "endPos": 12,
    "value": "hello world",
    "entity": "Greeting"
  },
  {
    "text": "hello world",
    "startPos": 0,
    "endPos": 6,
    "value": "hello",
    "entity": "Greeting"
  }
]

let result = a.reduce((acc, d) => {
  const found = acc.find(a => a.text == d.text);
  
  const { text, ...entitiesArray } = { ...d }; // <- Rest/Spread properties
  
  found ? found.entities.push(entitiesArray) 
        : acc.push({ text: d.text, entities: [entitiesArray]})

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `const entitiesArray = Object.assign({}, d);` its copying the entire object, which has `text` key also, I only want the selected properties, as described in the question.

Comment: Your input data does not match OPs input data.

Comment: `const { text, ...entitiesArray } = { ...d }; // <- Rest/Spread properties` what does this line do?

Comment: I have added link into it where you can read more. In concise, it gets the property `text` and assigns it to the `text` variable in the left side, rest properties are just copied into the `entitiesArray`

Answer (score 2):

You can also do a shorter version using `reduce` and `Object.values`

```js
let a = [{
    "text": "hello world",
    "startPos": 0,
    "endPos": 12,
    "value": "hello world",
    "entity": "Greeting"
  },
  {
    "text": "hello world",
    "startPos": 0,
    "endPos": 6,
    "value": "hello",
    "entity": "Greeting"
  }
];

let result = Object.values(a.reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v.text] = c[v.text] || {text: v.text,entities: []};
  c[v.text].entities.push(v);
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

---

Without the `text` property

```js
let a = [{
    "text": "hello world",
    "startPos": 0,
    "endPos": 12,
    "value": "hello world",
    "entity": "Greeting"
  },
  {
    "text": "hello world",
    "startPos": 0,
    "endPos": 6,
    "value": "hello",
    "entity": "Greeting"
  }
];

let result = Object.values(a.reduce((c, v) => {
  let {text: _,...o} = v;
  c[v.text] = c[v.text] || {text: v.text,entities: []};
  c[v.text].entities.push(o);
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new object with text and an array for the entitites.

This solution takes a destructed object and builds new objects with the keys.

```js
var a = [{ text: "hello world", startPos: 0, endPos: 12, value: "hello world", entity: "Greeting" }, { text: "hello world", startPos: 0, endPos: 6, value: "hello", entity: "Greeting" }],
    result = a.reduce((acc, { text, startPos, endPos, entity, value }) => {
        var found = acc.find(a => a.text === text),
            subEntity = { startPos, endPos, entity, value };

        if (found) {
            found.entities.push(subEntity);
        } else {
            acc.push({ text, entities: [subEntity] });
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) for [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) properties and [BABEL](https://babeljs.io/).

```js
var a = [{ text: "hello world", startPos: 0, endPos: 12, value: "hello world", entity: "Greeting" }, { text: "hello world", startPos: 0, endPos: 6, value: "hello", entity: "Greeting" }],
    result = a.reduce((acc, { text, ...subEntity }) => {
        var found = acc.find(a => a.text === text);

        if (found) {
            found.entities.push(subEntity);
        } else {
            acc.push({ text, entities: [subEntity] });
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: So I have to mention all the keys of the object here `a.reduce((acc, { text, startPos, endPos, entity, value }) => {` alongwith the accumulator?

Comment: actually yes, because the rest syntax does not work in all browsers.

Comment: The rest parameters are supported in browsers which support ES6 no?

Comment: it is not supported for objects. in function, it is supported.